# how to create dynamic tree structure with list of string paths using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of strings with are paths to some file with "/" separator that are available to my jsp/html page .
i.e.

```
d1/d2/d3/file1.c
d1/d2/d3/file2.java
d1/d2/file3.jsp
d1/d2/file4.asp
d1/d2/d3/d4/file4.asp
d11/d22/d33/file5.txt
```

The above list of string paths are available to my page. I need to make a dynamic tree structre with above data in below  tree structure using javascript.

```
+d1/d2/
 file3.jsp
 file4.asp

+d1/d2/d3/
 file1.c
 file2.java

+d1/d2/d3/d4/
 file4.asp

+d11/d22/d33/
 file5.txt
```

When I click on the common path like +di/d2 it should expand to show all the files under that directory , and when again click on it should hide the child files.
Simmilarly for all other nodes.

Comment: I removed the "ajax" tag because I don't see how this has any ajax invovled. For the actual question, your best bet would be to first convert those strings to hashes, and then do a deep hash merge. Then find a plug-in online for turn your javascript hash into a html/js tree menu. As it stands your question is not focused enough to get you a good response. You didn't even mention what javascript framework you are using (if any).

Comment: @user why don't you use some jquery plugin to build the tree structure ...instead of you doing it again

Comment: @user try this http://www.jstree.com/

Answer (score 4):

Since you have no code to show us, I'm not going to write it all for you. Just an overview, to tell you the method, you'll have to write your own code:

1. Store the paths as strings in javascript
2. Call string.split("/") on each of them and store results in arrays
3. Create object that will hold the tree
4. Match all top leveled arrays that are similar, and then append all of the unique top level directories as children to the object created in step 3.
5. Continue process using a trickle-down method, adding children to the children of the top level directories.
6. Render the results probably as a list, by appending the children to the list objects that you create, using the trickle down method again.

For reference: [Javascript building tree hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286031/javascript-building-tree-hierarchy)

Comment: Thanks LostInTheCode,
As per you suggestion I have implemented a tree structure using jquery with ahrd coded values of branch and nodes but unable to make step 5 and 6. I will really appreciate if you could give code snipet to step 5 and step 6 as explained by you.